# How do you configure kotlinx serialization in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am wondering how I can configure kotlinx as a default serialization in Spring Boot app.

For Jackson, I would use e.g. `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false`

But I haven't found any configuration options for kotlinx in Spring.

I know kotlinx supports this, I only cannot find a way to configure it on Spring level so that it works for example in controller method signatures:

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/foo")
fun fooMethod(
    @RequestBody fooJsonRequest: SomeDataClassRepresentingTheJson,
) {}
```

↑ Throws `HttpMessageNotReadableException` exception suggesting I use `ignoreUnknownKeys=true` when constructing `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json`. However I do not know where to do this so it would apply to Spring itself.

I have tried creating a bean providing Json object to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Publish a `@Bean` of the following type and customize `Json` constructor as needed:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun messageConverter(): KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter {
    return KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter(Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    })
}
```